# Flutter: cant get navigation to work in project

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

As a noob, I am trying some projects as boilerplate.
I'm having trouble with one.
I can get the whole project to work, except for the navigation.
I tried different solutions and docs, but I guess my noobness prevents me from seeing the correct issue and how to fix it.

This is the example I am using, again, its works, except for the bottom navigation to another "page": https://github.com/Sithira/FlutterRadioPlayer/tree/master/example/lib .
I need to add 1 or 2 pages and corresponding buttons for them.

Is anyone willing to push me in the correct direction or even supply a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a" solution is to use the `Navigator.of(context)` approach.

For this to work you have to change:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

to:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: MyApp(),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not doing anything to actually change the page being show on `setState()`

Try putting the second page on the list on children:

```
_children = [
    new FirstPage(),
    new SecondPage(),
  ];
```

Also, your forgetting to return the actual selected page. Try something like:

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Radio Player Example'),
        ),
        body: _children[_currentIndex]
```

This way, every time you `setState()` with a new index, the page will rebuild showing the new selected page based on the `_currentIndex` you've changed.

There's also a ton of other ways to handle navigation in Flutter. Some are:
The imperative approach with `Navigator.of(context).push)` / `pop()` etc..
The new declarative approach with `Navigator 2.0` and `Router Delegate`

Comment: Ive added the second page. yet i dont get the body part you suggested. Both _children and _currentIndex stay undefined.

Comment: You have to dynamically return the Page in the body based on the index. _children must be a list of Widgets that'll be your First and Second page. And the index is the current index you've selected with the nav bar

Comment: Try extracting everything within the body of the scaffold in a new widget. Add it to the list of children alongside with the SecondPage. Now return _children[_currentIndex] from the body.

Comment: Got it working using the Navigator.of(context) way. Had to change void main() => runApp(MyApp()); into void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: MyApp(),
    ));